# With vuejs, how do I get firebase (vuefire) object into component data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuefire, element-ui

Using firebase 4.10.1 and vuefire 1.4.5.

I have confirmed that I have initialized firebase, exported a `db` const, and imported vuefire correctly.

I am trying to load my firebase object (JSON) onto my `dataTable` component data.

I am trying this:

```
export default {
    firebase: function () {
       return {
           fbObj: db.ref('collection')
       }
    },
    data () {
        return {
            dataTable: fbObj
        }
    }
 }
```

It's wired up correctly because if I use `{{ fbObj }}` in my template I get the JSON object displayed in full. However, if I try to load it onto the dataTable I get `"fbObj is not defined"` as console error.

How can I load my firebase object onto the dataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```js
firebase: function () {
   return {
       fbObj: db.ref('collection')
   }
},
```

Creates a `this.fbObj` available to your Vue instance. So instead of `dataTable: fbObj` the correct would be more like:

```js
data () {
    return {
        dataTable: this.fbObj   // but even this won't work
    }
}
```

But that **won't work**. You can't do it because that `data()` initialization code will be executed before the `fbObj` has been initialized (it takes a bit of time to update it from firebase).

So if you want `dataTable` to refer to that collection, ***either***:

- **Rename** the firebase object to `dataTable`:

  ```js
  firebase: function () {
     return {
         dataTable: db.ref('collection')
     }
  },
  ```
- **Or** create a **computed** property:

  ```js
  firebase: function () {
     return {
         fbObj: db.ref('collection')
     }
  },
  computed: {
      dataTable() {
          return this.fbObj;
      }
  }
  ```

Then you can use `this.dataTable` in the Vue instance JavaScript or `dataTable` in the template.

Comment: Much thanks! I just renamed the firebase object and it worked as I wanted.